# Formatter tool to be called during a Mercurial commit from IntelliJ

Tags: ide, version-control, mercurial, code-conversion, file-conversion

When saving changes from the  [IntelliJ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) into the [Mercurial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) version control system, I suppose it makes sense to reformat the [source code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) files being submitted for consistency so irrelevant white-space etc. does not trigger false diffs.

Is there a formatter tool that can be called as part of the IntelliJ-Mercurial process?

To be clear… I want to use my own funky formatting rules while editing source code in IntelliJ. But I want to use a more common set of rules of formatting in the changes seen by Mercurial.